# Adding sphinx container docker-compose shows an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

i have an Ruby on Rails project, which i want to place into the containers( there are database, redis and web(includes rails project) containers). I want to add search feature, so i added a sphinx container in my compose file
docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-rails
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - redis
    - db
    **- sphinx**
  environment:
    - REDISTOGO_URL=redis://user@redis:6379/

redis:
  image: redis

**sphinx:
  image: centurylink/sphinx**

db:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
  build: .
  env_file: .env_db
```

`docker-compose build` works fine but when i run `docke-compose up` i get 
`ERROR: Cannot start container 096410dafc86666dcf1ffd5f60ecc858760fb7a2b8f2352750f615957072d961: Cannot link to a non running container: /metartaf_sphinx_1 AS /metartaf_web_1/sphinx_1`
How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://hub.docker.com/r/centurylink/sphinx/ the Sphinx container runs needs some amount of configuration files to run properly. See the *Daemonized usage (2). You need data source files and a configuration.

In my test, it fails to start as is with error:

```
FATAL: no readable config file (looked in /usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf, ./sphinx.conf)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `docker-compose.yml` shouldn't have these `*` in it.

If you want sphinx latest version you can do this:

```
web:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-rails
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - redis
    - db
    - sphinx
  environment:
    - REDISTOGO_URL=redis://user@redis:6379/

redis:
  image: redis

sphinx:
  image: centurylink/sphinx:latest

db:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
  build: .
  env_file: .env_db
```

If you want a specific version you write this way : `centurylink/sphinx:2.1.8`

Comment: I think he wanted just to bold sphinx container case. Thought its good idea to pin to versions.

Comment: Oh with markdown on StackOverflow I didn't get that